# Reinstalled Android Studio, can't compile project. Unable to upgrade Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I followed the in-Android Studio prompts to upgrade my gradle config to 2.2-all.zip .

I ran `sdk install gradle 2.2` in my terminal.

I restart Android Studio.

"Gradle project sync failed"

When I clicked "Try again" on the gradle build failed prompt, I get an error about jakewharton SDK manager. On their github they say the project is deprecrated, so I'm commenting out in dependencies

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
//        classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.+'
        classpath 'de.felixschulze.gradle:gradle-hockeyapp-plugin:3.2'
    }
```

with that commented out, I get

```
Error:Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 2.14.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/quantum/pocket-android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.2-all.zip.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
<a href="fixGradleVersionInWrapper">Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project</a><br><a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a>
```

My gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Wed Sep 21 20:05:48 EDT 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip
```

Event log:

```

```
Gradle sync failed: Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 2.14.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/quantum/pocket-android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.2-all.zip.
         Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
         Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Searching for "2.14" in my project has no results.

How do I upgrade my Gradle?

Comment: In your project's build.gradle file, inside of dependencies, change `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.14.1'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'`.

Comment: @TheAnonymous010 I think you meant change `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'` to use `2.2.0`? Regardless, the plugin version is different than the Gradle version

Comment: The code in my apps uses the line with 2.2.0 and not 1.2.3. Regardless, he fixed the problem so it's all good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have experienced it recently and found the following error a bit misleading:

```
Gradle sync failed: Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 2.14.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/quantum/pocket-android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.2-all.zip.
         Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
         Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

because `distributionUrl` already pointing to `gradle-2.2-all.zip`.

It turns out that we can solve it by setting gradle wrapper to default via:

```
Menu File -> Setings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Gradle
```

Then select **Use default gradle wrapper(recommended)**.

Comment: The error message states ***if** using the gradle wrapper*, then update the distributionUrl value. Otherwise, if you had to go change the setting to use the wrapper, then you needed to update your system installed Gradle version instead

Comment: Well said, but sometimes we forgot that we have change the gradle setting or Android Studio defaulting to `local gradle distribution`. So my argument still valid then.

Comment: Thank you! this worked.. however now when I run I have "upportedMethodException
         Unsupported method: AndroidProject.getPluginGeneration()." ...tried updating to 3.1 and installing 3.1 as the default with sdk, too. Any advice? I tried rebuilding and I get "Gradle version 2.2 is required" but I'm nto sure where that is set

Comment: like @TheAnonymous010 have said, try changing in your root build.gradle  the  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'`

Comment: Thanks. It sure did help.